# SBT failing to resolve dependency [ResolveException]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have the following in my **build.sbt** file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      scalaVersion := "2.13.4",
    )),
    name := "ScalaTest",
    resolvers += "spigot-repo" at "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/",
    libraryDependencies += "org.spigotmc" % "spigot-api" % "1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT" % "provided" intransitive(),
    version := "1.0"
  )
```

Which, when using IntelliJ and trying to refresh / reimport the project, a few issues occur:

- Dependencies won't resolve despite working with maven / Gradle.
- Produces the following error

```
/Users/harrydrummond/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/harrydrummond/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/IntelliJ IDEA.app.plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.7 (Oracle Corporation Java 15.0.1)
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/harrydrummond/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project t-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /Users/harrydrummond/Documents/workspace/scala/t/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to ScalaTest (in build file:/Users/harrydrummond/Documents/workspace/scala/t/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/harrydrummond/.sbt/1.0/server/26df0aea2f87fd17e7ab/sock
[info] started sbt server
sbt:ScalaTest>
;set _root_.scala.collection.Seq(historyPath := None,shellPrompt := { _ => "" }
,SettingKey[_root_.scala.Option[_root_.sbt.File]]
("sbtStructureOutputFile")
in _root_.sbt.Global := _root_.scala.Some(_root_.sbt.file("/private/var/folders/kf/q70qvrg10ls9qd7vvb8zlvgr0000gn/T/sbt-structure.xml"))
,SettingKey[_root_.java.lang.String]("sbtStructureOptions")
in _root_.sbt.Global := "download, resolveClassifiers")
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile and 1 others.
[info] The new values will be used by cleanKeepGlobs
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to ScalaTest (in build file:/Users/harrydrummond/Documents/workspace/scala/t/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/harrydrummond/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/203.7148.57/IntelliJ IDEA.app.plugins/Scala/repo/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2020.3/jars/sbt-structure-extractor.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to ScalaTest (in build file:/Users/harrydrummond/Documents/workspace/scala/t/)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/harrydrummond/.ivy2/localorg.spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error]   download error: Caught java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom (Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom) while downloading https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/harrydrummond/.ivy2/localorg.spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error]   download error: Caught java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom (Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom) while downloading https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/spigot-api-1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 21 Feb 2021, 16:54:13
[info] shutting down sbt server
```

Comment: In your log error it doesn't seem to be trying to fetch it from `https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/` Are you sure this is the version you are running? Try to save and rerun.

Comment: I assume by version I am running you mean is this actually in my sbt and trying to run this content in the build.sbt. I can confirm it is, and as for saving IntelliJ does this for you consistently so should be no problem. I also cannot ever get it to work with other external resolvers so it's not specific to this dependency. However, it does succeed when retrieving directly from maven central if that's any help.

Comment: You can see in https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d79jaLMcQMejhOGH9YJYNQ that we have 403. Is that the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: If that is the error you are getting, do you have credentials to access those packages? If so, I can help you configure them.

Comment: I don't require any credentials for the package. I access freely all the time with Gradle and maven. This is an example with Gradle `compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'` `maven { url = 'hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots' }` and no issues which leads me to believe this is an sbt issue. And yes, I believe I am getting a 403. I have the error message in the initial post